# Logstash: modify apache date format

Tags: apache, logstash, logstash-grok

The grok-filter `%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}` formats the timestamp as `dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z` however I need the timestamp in the format of `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`
I tried the below configuration

```
 grok {
       match => [
                  "message", "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}",
                ]
               break_on_match => false
     }
     date {
            match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
            target => ["datetime"]
     }
```

but got the below parsing error:

```
Failed parsing date from field {:field=>"timestamp", :value=>"19/May/2012:12:40:18 -0700", :exception=>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "19/May/2012:12:40:18 -0700" is malformed at "/May/2012:12:40:18 -0700", :level=>:warn}
```

Would highly appreciate if anyone can throw more light on the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The COMBINEDAPACHELOG pattern is expecting the date in the log entry to match the format so it can shove it into the "timestamp" field.  It doesn't *format* your timestamp at all.

Once the date has been grok'ed out into "timestamp", you can use the date{} filter to move it into @timestamp.  The pattern you supply there should match whatever's in the field.

So, pass "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" as the format to date{} and you should be all set.

EDIT:

Based on your additional details, I was hoping that you could match each component of the input date and then combine them into a new field.  That would work if you were trying to swap, say, firstName and lastName in a string, but dates are more complicated.  A simple string swap wouldn't handle converting "Jan" to "01" or deal with timezones at all.

So, we're back to creating a date object and then outputting that as a string in the format you desire.

```
# convert "timestamp" to a date field "datetime"
date {
    match => [ "timestamp", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
    target => ["datetime"]
}

# convert "datetime" to a string "datestring"
ruby {
    code => "
         event['datestring'] = event['datetime'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    "
}
```

Comment: The date field in Apache logs are like for instance 19/May/2012:12:40:18 -0700 whereas I want the date in the format of yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Perhaps an example would make this clear

Comment: Yes, I understood that.  Following the directions in my answer will give you a valid Elasticsearch date, which is stored as the proper type and is typically output in the format you mention.

Comment: I need timestamp in a desired format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L as am not using ElasticSearch as a backend but a http service instead

Answer (score 0):

For the latest version of Logstash the code would be:

@ convert "datetime" to a string "datestring"

```
ruby {
    code => "event.set('datestring', event.get('datetime').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))"
}
```